# Upload multiple files using s3upload in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Can we upload multiple files (not entire folder) to S3 using [`s3Upload`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin#s3upload) in Jenkins file?

I was trying to upload all rpm files (`*.rpm`) in the root directory to S3 using the `s3Upload` function.

Comment: And..? What happened?

Comment: IIRC `s3upload` only supports a single file or a directory. So either iterate over them using `findFiles('*.rpm')` and call `s3Upload` per file, or upload the complete directory.

Comment: Let me try this right away..

Comment: @StephenKing finFiles worked. `files = findFiles(glob: '*.rpm')

  files.each { 
      println "RPM:  ${it}"
      withAWS(credentials: '*********'){
        // s3Upload(file:"${it}", bucket:'bucket', path:"${bucket_path}")
        }
    }
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

findFiles solved the issue. Below is the snippet used for the same.

```
files = findFiles(glob: '*.rpm')

  files.each { 
      println "RPM:  ${it}"
      withAWS(credentials: '****************'){
       s3Upload(file:"${it}", bucket:'rpm-repo', path:"${bucket_path}")
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I do this IAM role assigned to that node running Jenkins pipeline? No credentials

Answer (score 6):

You can upload all the files with following command in one line.

```
  s3Upload(bucket:"my-bucket", path:'path/to/targetFolder/', includePathPattern:'**/*.svg', workingDir:'dist')
```

Further explaining, You can create own filtering based on following two possibilities;

1.Include all the files of a certain extention.

```
s3Upload(bucket:"my-bucket", path:'path/to/targetFolder/', includePathPattern:'**/*.svg', workingDir:'dist')
```

2.Include all the files except certain file extention.

```
s3Upload(bucket:"my-bucket", path:'path/to/targetFolder/', includePathPattern:'**/*', workingDir:'dist', excludePathPattern:'**/*.svg')
```

Reference: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin (Check under s3Upload)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following link [AWS s3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/). In that, refer section **'Use of Exclude and Include Filters'**

Here is a way to upload multiple files of a particular type.

If you only want to upload files with a particular extension, you need to first exclude all files, then re-include the files with the particular extension. This command will upload only files ending with .jpg:

```
aws s3 cp /tmp/foo/ s3://bucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.jpg"
```

This works for AWS Command Line Interface.

Comment: This answer is targeting the `aws` CLI. I assume that the OP means the Pipeline AWS Plugin's step.

Comment: @StephenKing is right. s3Upload is for Jenkins pipeline step

Comment: As per official documentation given on [link](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-aws/) s3Upload supports uploading individual files or uploading the whole directory (including all subfolders). So I tried to give an alternate solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

For pipelines, you need to wrap the iteration in `script`, like

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    // Extract concise branch name.
    BRANCH = GIT_BRANCH.substring(GIT_BRANCH.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, GIT_BRANCH.length())
  }
  ...
  post {
    success {
      script {
        def artifacts = ['file1', 'dir2/file3']
        artifacts.each {
          withAWS(credentials:'my-aws-token', region:'eu-west-1') {
            s3Upload(
              file: "build/${it}",
              bucket: 'my-artifacts',
              path: 'my-repo/',
              metadatas: ["repo:${env.JOB_NAME}", "branch:${env.BRANCH}", "commit:${env.GIT_COMMIT}"]
            )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this is great solution, it's imprortant to add that it will work only after installation of the following plugin: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-aws/